# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<Sampling__c>

Tags: apex, trigger

I've been looking around for awhile now trying to figure out how to fix this and I am unable to locate what could be wrong with this.

I am trying to create 2 objects, one that holds my Sampling Object and one that holds my Product Object.  When I build my Sampling Object I want to get all the information where Responsible_for_EVB_Build1 is null so it can be populated from my Product object where it is usually not null.  Am I going about this right or is my logic wrong?

```
List<Sampling__c> sampObj =([SELECT Product__c, Name,Id,Responsible_for_EVB_Build1__c FROM Sampling__c WHERE Responsible_for_EVB_Build1__c = null ]);               
system.debug('Product Object === ' +sampObj);

 List < Product2 > prodObj = new List<Product2>([Select Name,AE2__c From Product2 WHERE Id = : sampObj.Product__c]);        
    system.debug('1stParentsampObj === ' +prodObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong I think:

```
List < Product2 > prodObj = new List<Product2>([Select Name,AE2__c From Product2 WHERE Id = : sampObj.Product__c]);
```

sampObj is a list - so you can't filter where Id = on a list - you need to use an IN statement. You can try changing it to the line below so that it is filtering for all records IN the sampObj List - but depending on what the Product__c field is, you might need to loop through sampObj to build a unique set of Product Ids, and then filter for that instead

```
List < Product2 > prodObj = new List<Product2>([Select Name,AE2__c From Product2 WHERE Id IN :sampObj.Product__c]);
```

Comment: Product__c is a Lookup field related to Product.

Comment: Something like this should work right? 
List < Product2 > prodObj = new List<Product2>([Select Name,AE2__c From Product2 WHERE Id IN :[SELECT Product__c,Id,Name From Sampling__c]]);

Comment: Maybe - but I think you'd be better to query for a unique set of Product Ids

Comment: I ended up Nuking it and starting over, I will try it that way

Comment: Finished it.. works perfect, good suggestion BritishBoy